# Summing of averages

Tags: ssas

SSAS 2012, AdventureWorks Tabular Model SQL 2012

Having a hierarchy of some fields, want to list values from a measure per month in a year, then see average value for month, then sum these averages on all hierarchy levels up.

Example: (all measures in table 'Internet Sales')

```
ComplexCalculation:=[Internet Total Sales]*[UnitPriceAvg]/1000
UnitPriceAvg:=AVERAGE('Internet Sales'[Unit Price])
AvgComplexCalculation:=AVERAGEX(VALUES('Date'[Month]), [ComplexCalculation])
AverageAndSumComplexCalculation:=IF( ISFILTERED(Product[Product Name]), [AvgComplexCalculation], SUMX (VALUES (Product[Product Name]), [AvgComplexCalculation]))
```

Pivot Fields:

```
Filters: [Calendar Year] [2006]
Rows: [Product Category Name],[Product SubCategory Name],[Model Name],[Product Name],[Month]
Columns:
Values: [AverageAndSumComplexCalculation]
```

Is it the right way of doing this? Noticed that when my "ComplexCalculation" measure becomes more and more complex it needs lot of time to calculate the values (causes timeout).

Comment: Is it desirable to take an average of monthly averages rather than averaging the base data for the year?

Comment: All the calculations should be per year - that's why I have [Calendar Year] in filters. The average should be calculated for last level - [Product Name]. Then all other levels up [Product Category Name],[Product SubCategory Name],[Model Name] should display sum of those averages.